# Servo start to turn like madman with simple if statement

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, servo

I tried to write a simple program. Press button 1 servo goes to position 1, press button 2 servo goes to position 2.

But when I hook everything up my Servo goes full Crazy mode. It starts to jiggle back and forth like a madman. Even when I unhook the buttons.

What is the mistake I made? Any help is appreciated :D

Thanks in advance

```c
/* Sweep
     by BARRAGAN <http://barraganstudio.com>
     This example code is in the public domain.

     modified 8 Nov 2013
     by Scott Fitzgerald
     http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sweep

    modified 5-12-2017
*/

#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo

int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int buttonState2 = 0;        // variable for reading the pushbutton status
const int buttonPin = 4;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int buttonPin2 = 5;    // the number of the pushbutton pin

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);         // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    myservo.write(173);        // tell servo to go to position
    delay(25);                 // waits 25ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  if (buttonState2 == HIGH) {
    myservo.write(97);         // tell servo to go to position
    delay(25);                 // waits 25ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
}
```

[image: photo]

Comment: How did you connect the buttons to the Arduino? Schematic please.

Comment: added a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, connect the buttons to the ground and change the code:

```c
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo

int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int buttonState2 = 0;        // variable for reading the pushbutton status
const int buttonPin = 4;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int buttonPin2 = 5;    // the number of the pushbutton pin

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    myservo.write(173);              // tell servo to go to position
    delay(300);                       // waits 25ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  if (buttonState2 == LOW) {
    myservo.write(97);              // tell servo to go to position
    delay(300);                       // waits 25ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
}
```

Pull-up resistors get a high input level when the buttons are open. Otherwise, electromagnetic interference may occur.

Comment: Very cool it stopped randomly moving!. Now it goes to the 2 positons. Yet one of those positions it keeps "buzzing" like some of the gears are still turning but I dont see any rotation as result. The second Position is Silent and very nice :D Do you know how this buzzing can be removed?

Comment: Please try to increase the delay from 25 to 300.